# Inner product of $p$-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, exterior-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extension of Riemannian Metric to Higher Forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22550/extension-of-riemannian-metric-to-higher-forms)

I have no problems with understanding the inner product of 1-forms on a Riemannian manifold. We have a metric tensor, it's inverse defines the metric in the cotangent space.

However I'm not very comfortable with the definition of inner product of $p$-froms with $p>1$. It is defined as

$$
\langle x^1 \land x^2 \land \ldots \land x^p, y^1 \land y^2 \land \ldots \land y^p \rangle = \det(\langle x^i y^j \rangle)
$$

Is there a way to hide the determinant? Or at least to write it as a determinant of a sensible linear operator, not just some matrix.

Comment: Please take a look if [this](http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/inner-products-on-differential-forms/) helps

Comment: To "hide" the determinant you may use the Hodge star as in [Geometry of Differential Forms](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=5N33Of2RzjsC) on p. 151, see Proposition 4.7 (iv)

Comment: @YuriVyatkin I'm actually asking about inner product, because I'm learning how Hodge star is defined through it :-)

Comment: By the way, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22550/) question is very relevant, and in fact answers yours.

Comment: Indeed, that what I was looking for.